# Heapsort implementation

Tags: heapsort

enter code here

```
 # include <iostream>
 # include <stdlib.h>
 # define MAX 10
 void heapsort(int A[]);
 void Build_MAX_Heap(int A[]);
 void MAX_Heapify(int A[],int i);
 int Left(int i);
 int Right(int i);
 void swap(int *num,int *num2);
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
 int H[100],i;
 for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    H[i]=rand();
 cout << "the given array is::" << " ";
 for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
     cout  << H[i] << "\n";
 cout << "\n" << "\n";
 heapsort(H);
 cout << "the sorted array is ::" << " ";
 for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    cout << H[i] << "\n";
 }
 void heapsort(int A[])
  {
    int i,heapsize;
     Build_MAX_Heap(A);
   for(i=MAX-1;i>0;i--)
  {
     swap(&A[0],&A[i]);
    heapsize=heapsize-1;
    MAX_Heapify(A,0);

  }
 }
 void Build_MAX_Heap(int A[])
 {
int heapsize,i;
heapsize=MAX;
for(i=(MAX)/2;i>0;i--)
{
    MAX_Heapify(A,i);
}
 }
void MAX_Heapify(int A[],int i)
{
int l,r,largest,heapsize;
l=Left(i);
r=Right(i);
if(l<=heapsize && A[l]>A[i])
    largest=l;
else
    largest=i;
if(r<=heapsize && A[r]>A[i])
    largest=r;
if(largest!=i)
{
    swap(&A[i],&A[largest]);
    MAX_Heapify(A,largest);
}
 }

int Left(int i)
{
return (2*i);
}
int Right(int i)
{
return (2*i+1);
}
```

`   void swap(int *num1,int *num2)
    {
    int temp;
    temp=*num1;
    *num1=*num2;
    *num2=temp;
    }
whats wrong in my code.its not sorting.It shows the outout but not in the sorted order.please help.thanks for the same

Answer (score 0):

There are a few flaws in your code.

- The notation of left child being (2 * i), and right child being (2 * i + 1), is valid, if you are using your array as 1-indexed. But as you are using your arrays as 0-indexed, you must change them to, left child = (2 * i + 1), right child = (2 * i + 2).
- Next thing, the variable 'heapsize' in your function 'MAX_Heapify()' is not initialised. You are using an unassigned variable, which is incorrect.
- In your heap sort procedure, you are deleting the max element and decreasing the size of the heap. But your are not using the new size anywhere. You are supposed to pass it to 'MAX_Heapify()' so that the procedure knows its bounds.
- Lastly, I think you must run the loop for heapify in Build_MAX_Heap till (i >= 0), i.e., for all the elements above (MAX / 2), including the root.

Correct these and re-write your code and I think you should be fine. If you to learn more about Binary Heaps with sketches and code, you can check my blog post on [Binary Heaps](https://theoryofprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/binary-heaps/).

I hope my answer has helped you, if it did, let me know...! ☺